# Correct Scala way to Loop/map 2 Lists and merge into 1 list

Tags: scala, list, merge

Very new to Scala if for example have 2 Lists

```
val list1: List[Int] = List(10,11)
val list2: List[Int] = List(1,2,3)
```

Want to create a list like this:

```
List((10,1),(10,2),(10,3),(11,1),(11,2),(11,3))
```

How would I go about doing this?
Sorry if this has been asked before, please feel free to link me the answer if it has been answered before and I'll gladly close this, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for start

```
list1.flatMap(x => list2.map(y => (x, y)))
```

...the combination of calls to `flatMap` and `map` indicates that a `for` comprehension will also work...

```
for (x <- list1; y <- list2) yield (x, y)
```

...there might be other ways as well. I believe that in most cases the compiler is clever enough to replace the `for` comprehension with the byte code equivalent to the `flatMap` and `map` approach so the two should be equivalent performance wise (although I didn't test this)...

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect, the yield one is interesting.